# Abstract / Interface design for user choosable window

Tags: java, android

I have an app with a user configurable object, `MyObject`, which allows a user to choose a specific type of window to display at a later date. At this point the choices will end up as either a `DialogFragment` or a `FragmentActivity`.

The idea is that a later date when `MyObject` is called up, the app will display the Dialog / Fragment based on the option chosen in the configured `MyObject`. Essentially the functionality of both types of windows will be the same, just different presentations.

I started by creating an *abstract* class setup to do something along these lines

```
public abstract MyDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private static mDialog;

    public abstract void close();
    public abstract void open();
    public abstract void start();
    public abstract void stop();

    public MyDialog (MyObject myO) {
        switch (myO.getDialogType()) {
            case 1: // MyDialog1
                mDialog = new MyDialog1(myO);
                break;
            case 2: // MyDialog2
                mDialog = new MyDialog2(myO);
                break;
        }

        mDialog.open();
    }
}

public MyDialog1 extends MyDialog {

    @override
    pubilic void onCreateDialog() {

    }

    // other implemented methods...
}

public MyDialog2 extends MyDialog {

    @override
    pubilic void onCreateDialog() {

    }

    // other implemented methods...
}
```

Where I am stuck is that I now am trying to add in the same heirachy with `ActivityFragment`, I can no longer extend `MyDialog`. I tried to have `MyDialog` extend `Fragment` and then child classes extend either `DialogFragment` or `FragmentActivity`, but that runs in to multiple-inheritance which can't happen.

**Is there a way to extend both types, `DialogFragment` and `ActivityFragment` from the same base class in my app?**

Should I instead do something more complex like this, using two case statements? I've never used this much in the way of abstraction, so am I incorrectly using it?

```
public MyApp extends FragmentActivity {

    MyObject mMyO;

    public void someEvent() {
        if (mMyO.getDisplayType() == "Activity") {
            MyActivity myA;
            switch (mMyO.getType()) {
            case 1: // MyActivity1
                myA = new MyActivity1(mMyO);
                break;
            case 2: // MyActivity2
                myA = new MyActivity2(mMyO);
                break;
            }
            myA.open();
        }

        if (mMyO.getDisplayType() == "Dialog") {
            MyDialog myD;
            switch (mMyO.getType()) {
            case 1: // MyDialog1
                myD = new MyDialog1(mMyO);
                break;
            case 2: // MyDialog2
                myD = new MyDialog2(mMyO);
                break;
            }
            myD.open();
        }
    }
}

public MyDialog1 extends MyDialog {

    @override
    pubilic void onCreateDialog() {

    }

    // other implemented methods...
}

public MyDialog2 extends MyDialog {

    @override
    pubilic void onCreateDialog() {

    }

    // other implemented methods...
}

public MyActivity1 extends MyActivity {

    @override
    pubilic void onCreate() {

    }

    // other implemented methods...
}

public MyActivity2 extends MyActivity {

    @override
    pubilic void onCreate() {

    }

    // other implemented methods...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look I'm no OO guy. I prefer functional but Wanted to test myself here. So let's follow the mvc idea. You have a model, myobject, and a choice of two views , dialogue or activity. The correct place to crystallize the mapping between views and objects is a controller, right? Your two views can extend a View class. Your app should not be extending a view class. It should rather extend a Controller class.

Also are you class-ifying different UI activities or events? I don't think you should do that unless you will take a couple of events in gestalt. In that case have a ComplexEvent superclass and either a list of events to trap, or subclasses that serve the same purpose.